# Android: MediaPlayer not getting released as expected

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

So I have an application with a ListView that plays audio in one of the fragments. The issue is, that some users are reporting that the application stops playing audio after a certain amount of clicks. I know this is an issue that has to do with the MediaPlayer not being released correctly, but I cannot find a place where I am not releasing it. Hopefully you guys can help.

Here is where MediaPlayer is being used in MyAudioFragment.java. I am fairly certain that the issue is located in these lines of code.

MyAudioFragment.java

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(MainActivity.mediaPlayer != null && MainActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.release();
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            }
            MainActivity.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), MainActivity.hashMap.get(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)));
            MainActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Here is where I deal with MediaPlayer in MainActivity.java

```
//...
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
//...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    //Layout stuff
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    //Setting up fragment stuff
    //...
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

Edit: Could it possibly be that I am not releasing it "OnCompletion" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On onCompletion, you must do release();

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. Thank you.